# urlset tag issue when creating sitemap.xml using classic ASP

Tags: xml, asp-classic, sitemap, xmldom

I am using classic ASP to create sitemap.xml files however I am getting a small issue which I cant figure out.  My objective is to obey this:

http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

The issue in my output. I can not figure out how to stop the xmlns="" being printed inside the url tag. it should only be showing in the urlset tag

Here is the cut n paste working ASP/VBScript:

```
Dim theDom, theRoot, theParent,theChild, theID, docInstruction

Set theDom = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
Set theRoot = theDom.createElement("urlset")

Set theID = theDom.createAttribute("xmlns")
theID.Text = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
theRoot.setAttributeNode theID
theDom.appendChild theRoot

Set theParent = theDom.createElement("url")     
  Set theChild = theDom.createElement("loc")
  theChild.Text = "http://someURL.com"
  theRoot.appendChild theParent
  theParent.appendChild theChild

  Set theChild = theDom.createElement("changefreq")
  theChild.Text = "weekly"
  theRoot.appendChild theParent
  theParent.appendChild theChild

Set theParent = theDom.createElement("url")     
  Set theChild = theDom.createElement("loc")
  theChild.Text = "http://someOtherUrl.com"
  theRoot.appendChild theParent
  theParent.appendChild theChild

  Set theChild = theDom.createElement("changefreq")
  theChild.Text = "weekly"
  theRoot.appendChild theParent
  theParent.appendChild theChild

Set docInstruction = theDom.createProcessingInstruction("xml","version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'")
theDom.insertBefore docInstruction, theDom.childNodes(0)
theDom.Save Server.MapPath("MyXMLDoc.xml")
```

and here is the output of the XML file it creates. How can I stop the xmlns="" from showing in the url tag but make sure it stays in the urlset tag??

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 - <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  - <url xmlns="">
     <loc>http://someURL.com</loc> 
     <changefreq>weekly</changefreq> 
    </url>
 - <url xmlns="">
    <loc>http://someOtherUrl.com</loc> 
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq> 
   </url>
  </urlset>
```

Comment: I have looked and looked at this and can not see what could be causing my issue.  Anybody??  Does anybody have an opinion if xmlns="" being in the url tag is even an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using CreateNode rather than CreateElement. If you pass the namespace as the third argument, the xmlns attribute isn't added to the element anymore. Something like this works for me:

```
Dim theDom, theRoot, theParent,theChild, theID, docInstruction

const NODE_ELEMENT = 1
const xmlns = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"

Set theDom = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
Set theRoot = theDom.createElement("urlset")

Set theID = theDom.createAttribute("xmlns")
theID.Text = xmlNs
theRoot.setAttributeNode theID
theDom.appendChild theRoot

Set theParent = theDom.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "url", xmlns)     
Set theChild = theDom.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "loc", xmlns)
theChild.Text = "http://someURL.com"
theRoot.appendChild theParent
theParent.appendChild theChild

Set theChild = theDom.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "changefreq", xmlns)
theChild.Text = "weekly"
theRoot.appendChild theParent
theParent.appendChild theChild

Set theParent = theDom.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "url", xmlns)     
Set theChild = theDom.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "loc", xmlns)
theChild.Text = "http://someOtherUrl.com"
theRoot.appendChild theParent
theParent.appendChild theChild

Set theChild = theDom.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "changefreq", xmlns)
theChild.Text = "weekly"
theRoot.appendChild theParent
theParent.appendChild theChild

Set docInstruction = theDom.createProcessingInstruction("xml","version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'")
theDom.insertBefore docInstruction, theDom.childNodes(0)
theDom.Save Server.MapPath("MyXMLDoc.xml")
```

It generates the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://someURL.com</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://someOtherUrl.com</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
  </url>
</urlset>
```